# How to pass notedate for User Notes in Netsuite using RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite

I could create and update User Notes in Netsuite for the customer.
The following data is working fine.

```
$columns_field= array("title","direction","notedate"); #_scheduled
$columns_values=array("Sample User Notes","2","4/30/2016");
$datastring = array('recordtype' => 'note', 'id' => '104','columnname' =>$columns_field,'columnvalues'=>$columns_values,'gu_action'=>'update');
```

But when i add time for notedate , it will not work. I want to pass date and time. i have tried these formats.

Like

1. 4/30/2016 05:06 am
2. 4/30/2016 05:06 AM
3. 4/30/2016 14:32

I am having RESTlet file in the following link:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ganeshprabhus/68a9e5b81e53436bb1d684f857a6c31f/raw/67fe03895f1c31d65c1f283dd51584af45d27c59/NS_Script_2016.2004.

My reference link is : 
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_2/schema/record/note.html

Additional Requirement : 
If possible, Please post the reference links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Note record date and time are separate fields. Their script ids are "notedate" and "time" respectively.

So if you have a real Date:

```
note.setFieldValue("notedate", nlapiDateToString(datetime)); //'date' format i s the default
note.setFieldValue("time" , nlapiDateToString(datetime, 'timeofday'));
```

Comment: Thanks bknights. It works fine. any chance to know reference links?

Comment: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_1/script/record/note.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `"2015-03-25T12:00:00"` for your date string. That's a format that the Javascript Date object will understand, which is what you're ultimately working with in NetSuite (actually it's Rhino + Java, but close enough)

BTW, the `T` above stands for UTC time, so make sure to keep that in mind.

Comment: I was always curious what the JS engine behind NS was. I wonder if it will ever transition to a modern engine.